# 'onEdit' function doesn't always fire when editing multiple cells quickly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Purpose**

This is for a checklist.
People type 'x' into a cell.  If x is the only thing in the cell, it should change to ✓

**Script**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  if (r.getValue() === 'x' || r.getValue() === 'X') {
    r.setValue('✓');
    r.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  }
}
```

**Problem**

Going slowly works.

But when inputting quickly (ie: type 'x', move to another cell with the arrow keys, type 'x', move, [quickly repeat this multiple times]), some cells change, but some remain as x.

---

**EDIT:**
I now have a working (but inelegant) solution.  I'd still like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

### This works

```
// Checks 300 rows and 11 columns, starting from E10 (row 10, col 5)
// if the value is 'x' or 'X', it changes it to a '✓'

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  var values = sheet.getRange(10, 5, 300, 11).getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++) {
      if ( values[i][j] === 'x' || values[i][j] === 'X') {
        var cell = sheet.getRange( 10 + i, 5 + j );
        cell.setValue('✓');
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This checks *every* cell in the tables (3300 of them) each time onEdit fires.  Since onEdit seems to always catch the last edit (but not the ones in between), this changes every x to ✓.

---

**Background**

At work, I've been asked to convert a checklist into a Google Doc.  There are hundreds of checkboxes in various tables.

I've been asked to make the boxes have checks, ✓, since we print and show this checklist to clients.

Many of my colleagues are not computer literate, so the input method has to be very simple.

**Questions**

Is there a way to fix the original script, or is there another better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onEdit() doesn't catch all changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856739/onedit-doesnt-catch-all-changes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if having data validation is an option? Else you can do this;

- type in a cell: =char(10003) which will output as ✓
- create data validation and choose list with items
- copy the symbol (not the formula) and paste it in the box (and put a comma behind it)
- if you need another symbol for not completed, repeat the previous steps with =char(10005), which will output as ✕

Besides that you can maybe use the square root symbol, which on my mac is easily entered using option-shift-V and looks like √ (you will have to look up that combination for your OS).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've been trying the data validation method as you suggested, but it adds a lot of extra input time. (1. select cell 2. enter or click to select cell 3. arrow or mouse to ✓ 4. enter or click on ✓, [repeat])  We have so many cells, and people have many of these lists to do, so we were looking for a quicker method (1. select cell, 2. press a key, [repeat])

Comment: As for the √ (option-v) method, for some reason google sheets requires the extra "enter or click to edit cell" step (tried on FF & Chrome).  You can't just type it like a normal character.  Also, my boss doesn't like the look of it.