# onEdit() doesn't catch all changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this simple trigger script that should add a timestamp in the next column. simple, onEdit doesn't catch all edits. 
Can I do anything in the settings?

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.value == "TRUE") {e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date())} 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `LockService`?

Comment: https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/05/27/detecting-quickly-checked-checkboxes-on-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/

Answer (score 5):

About your situation, there is [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52811408/7108653). In this thread, [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) says that

> This is a known limitation of onEdit.

About the direct solution of this issue, it is required to wait for Google's update.

Here, I would like to think of a workaround for your situation. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

**This workaround supposes that there are the checkboxes in the range of "F1:F20".**

1. Check whether the edited range is in "F1:F20".
2. If the edited range is in "F1:F20", retrieve values of "F1:F20" and check each value.
3. Create an array for putting the result.
4. Overwite the created array to "F1:F20".

By this, although it might be not perfect, it can be artificially achieved. Please think of this as just one of several workarounds.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.columnEnd == 6 && e.range.rowStart <= 20) {
    var ckeckboxRange = "F1:F20";
    var date = new Date();
    var range = e.source.getRange(ckeckboxRange);
    var values = range.getValues().map(function(e) {return e[0] === true ? [date] : [""]});
    range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Ahmed AbdelKhalek Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Where in the documentation or how with debugging can I see columnStart and columnEnd I see e.range in the google documentation but am unaware how to find out a list of objects like columnStart and End... where do you find this?

Comment: @CodeCamper Thank you for replying. About `columnStart` and `columnEnd` in `range` of the event object, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248888