# Trigger function by checking checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

[image]

I have a sheet with checkboxes in the first column.  I would like to be able to trigger a function by checking a box. Right now all the checkboxes are set to false/unchecked. Is there anyway to trigger an event by checking a box?

Comment: See [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite)

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54856739/7108653

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onEdit() doesn't catch all changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856739/onedit-doesnt-catch-all-changes)

Comment: This is interesting. I see that the event can have a range. Is there information on which sheet in a spreadsheet that generated it?

Comment: @user61629 Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your comment, if ``function onEdit(e) {}`` is used, the spreadsheet ID and the edited sheet name can be retrieved by ``e.source.getId()`` and ``e.source.getSheetName()``, respectively.

Comment: Yes , that's what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: @user61629 I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, can you post it as an answer and accept it? By this, other users can see your question as the resolved question.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've entered an answer, but I don't think it adds anything not in the other threads. I'm still trying to decide what to do next.

Comment: @user61629 Thank you for replying. I apologize for my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is not much of an answer, but does log ONEDIT when clicking or unclicking a checkbox. Maybe it can be used as a start for something more complicated.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.columnEnd == 1 && e.range.rowStart <= 2000) {
    Logger.log('ONEDIT');

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score -4):

When you Insert a checkbox, the cell value can either be true or false. So, in my opinion, create a function "status_check" and do the following:

1. Create a Trigger which executes status_check function every minute.
2. Insert an "IF" condition, if the status of the cell is false, then do nothing.
3. if "IF" is true then execute the necessary code.

This will work seamlessly with lag of just a minute.

Comment: A lag of one minute is a total showstopper in general.