# Delay on Google Script Editor (For Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, java, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm just curious if there is a way around this error I keep on having.
I have a document where multiple people are filling in information, and require it to populate the cell adjacent to it with their username. The code below is as follows (bare in mind I only want this to take effect in column J, H and F):

```
    function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
       var r = s.getActiveCell();
       var username = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
       if (r.getColumn() == 10) { //checks the J column
           var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
           Logger.log(nextCell.getValue());
               nextCell.setValue(username);
       }
         if (r.getColumn() == 8) { //checks the H column
           var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
           Logger.log(nextCell.getValue());
               nextCell.setValue(username);
       }
         if (r.getColumn() == 6) { //checks the F column
           var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
           Logger.log(nextCell.getValue());
               nextCell.setValue(username);
       }
   }
```

This code itself seems to be working fine, but the problem i seem to find is that if too many cells are updated too quickly, it will not pick up.

[image: Example of the problem]

Do you know if there is a way for the script to run more efficiently? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this workaround useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857855

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I didnt see that there was already a question in this field.
I'll give it a go know and let you know.

Comment: I think that also in your situation, that workaround can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  if (e.range.columnStart==10 || e.range.columnStart==8 || e.range.columnStart==6) { 
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getUsername());
  }
}
```

- [onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)