# How to optimize my code to make sure it locks every cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to use google sheet for data recording and verification. For example, person A input data in A1:C1, then when person B tick checkbox at D1, it will locks A1:C1 to prevent person A from editing again. This process will repeat for every row.

I managed to make the code work. But, it seems like sometimes when person B tick the checkbox quickly, the code may overlook one or two rows and do not lock every row. For example, when person B tick D1, D2 & D3, the system locks 1 and 3 row only.

How do I optimize the code so that it will always lock every row without missing one or two?

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1,3)
  var protectSs = range.protect().setDescription('Protect row ' + row);  
  var a = sheet.getRange(row,4,1,1).getValues();

  if (col == 4){ 
    if (a == "true") {

      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protectSs.addEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
      protectSs.removeEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
      Logger.log(me);
     }

     else if (a == "false") {

      protectSs.addEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
      protectSs.removeEditor("guest1@gmail.com");

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54856739/7108653

Comment: As indicated in the link provided by @Tanaike, this is a limitation of Google Sheets. Notably, it's a huge limitation of spreadsheets treated like applications: they're not great for multiple active users. You should look for alternatives such as using separate sheets, row highlighting to indicate protected states, using Forms, creating an app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First put checkboxes in column 4 thus removing any  other possible entries in that range.  Then try this script.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var rg=sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1, 1,3)
  var protectSs=range.protect().setDescription('Protect row ' + e.range.rowStart);  
  if (e.range.columnStart==4){ 
    if (e.value=="TRUE") {
      protectSs.addEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
      protectSs.removeEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
     }
     else {
      protectSs.addEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
      protectSs.removeEditor("guest1@gmail.com");
     }
   }
}
```