# onEdit(e) executes too quickly before it can finish

Tags: google-apps-script

onEdit(e) seems to stop executing halfway if I edit too quickly which is breaking the logic of my code, how to make sure every onEdit properly executes and finishes?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857855/7108653

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onEdit() doesn't catch all changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856739/onedit-doesnt-catch-all-changes)