# Google Sheets time clock stamp script too slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script for clock-in and clock-out to track time worked and efficiency. The script makes time stamps in progressing columns any time a check box is clicked and then finds the difference between each 'Check In' and 'Check Out' time to spit out a 'Total time worked' in a separate cell.

If the check box is checked that means the employee is working and when the box is unchecked they are either done or taking a break and their time is added to their total for that task. They could clock in and clock out a few times with their time being added to their total.

The issue is the script is running so slowly that it sometimes misses the time stamp and effectively makes the sheet useless.

I'm pretty new with Google's scripts so I know this is not optimized and could be cleaned up, but I don't really know what causes it to go so slow. Any suggestions would be great. Script below, and I can link to a dummy sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B3xcmV4FBIUjxd_bzBD4mytbLyEPyubWVdvZDLTQsJE/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
 addTimestamp(e);
  
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var startRow = 18;
  var targetColumn = 2;
  var col26 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,26).getValue();
  var col27 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).getValue();
  var col28 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,28).getValue();
  var col29 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,29).getValue();
  var col30 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).getValue();
  var col31 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,31).getValue();
  var col32 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,32).getValue();
  var col33 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,33).getValue();


  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow ){
    
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col26 ==""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,26).setValue(currentDate);}
    
  if(col27 =="" && col26 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).setValue(currentDate);}  
  if(col28 =="" && col27 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,28).setValue(currentDate);}  
  if(col29 =="" && col28 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,29).setValue(currentDate);}      
  if(col30 =="" && col29 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(currentDate);}  
  if(col31 =="" && col30 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,31).setValue(currentDate);}  
  if(col32 =="" && col31 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,32).setValue(currentDate);}  
  if(col33 =="" && col32 != ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,33).setValue(currentDate);} 
    
     //END IF check if date created exists
  } // END IF check column, row, worksheet
} // END function
```

Comment: Try following this: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can I ask you about the detail situation of `The issue is the script is running so slowly that it sometimes misses the time stamp and effectively makes the sheet useless.`?

Comment: Hello Tanaike! When the checkbox is clicked, the script makes a timestamp in a column. When it is unchecked another time stamp is put in the next column over. Each time stamp takes a few seconds for the script to process and then add. If other actions are done quickly after the checkbox is hit it sometimes does not place a time stamp at all. Hopefully that clarifies. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that unfortunately, your issue is the current specification. Although there is the workaround [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857855), in your case, when the checkbox is unchecked, you want to also detect. In this case, this workaround cannot know whether the checkbox was checked or unchecked just now. In this case, also the lock service cannot be used. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/7b1a18a5b768e4d69d519069f4aff440) I apologize for this situation. When I found other workaround, I would like to post is as an answer.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for **Best practices**. Your script has too many  getValue and setValue calls.

Comment: I found a solution that addresses TheMaster that there are too many getValue and setValue. The script here seems to work the same as the original:

function onEdit(e){
var row, col, sh;
row = e.range.rowStart; 
col = e.range.columnStart; 
sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if(col === 2 && row >= 18 ){
var arr, ind;
arr = sh.getRange(row, 26, 1, 8).getValues();
ind = arr[0].findIndex((value) => !value)
sh.getRange(row, 26 + ind).setValue(new Date())
} 
}

What @Tanaike said seems to be correct with the issue coming from onEdit() not tracking changes. Looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function addTimestamp(e){
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const dt=new Date();
  var l=1;
  if(e.range.rowStart>17 && e.range.columnStart==2 && sh.getName()=="Batch") {
    //e.source.toast('conditional');
    var vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,26,1,8).getValues()[0];
    vs.forEach(function(el,i){
      if(el=='' && l!='')vs[i]=dt;
      l=el;     
    });
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,26,1,8).setValues([vs]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper,
Thanks for your reply. I tried the new script but it did not seem to create any time or date stamps. Should they be appearing in a column somewhere or am I missing something else?

Comment: No luck. Should I be getting time stamps somewhere or making any other changes to the sheet?

Comment: You should be getting timestamps starting in column 26 (Z)